# apache equivalent of jetty rewrite rule

Tags: regex, apache, url-rewriting, jetty

I have a URL re write rule in jetty.xml file which is working fine on my local environment and I am having a slight trouble converting it into apache rule for my testing site.

This is my jetty.xml rule looks like

```
<Call name="addRule">
    <Arg>
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteRegexRule">
            <Set name="regex">^/(da|de|el|en|es|fr|it|nl|pl|pt|ru|sv|tr|es_419|pt_br)/samplePage</Set>
            <Set name="replacement">/samplePage.html</Set>
        </New>
    </Arg>
</Call>
```

In my apache file I have written the same rule like this, but for some reason it doesn't seems to work.

```
RewriteRule ^/(en|es|fr|it|de)/samplePage /samplePage.html [P]
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need `P` (proxy) flag here.

Try this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?(en|es|fr|it|de)/samplePage /samplePage.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: it resulted into page not found error. Although I have the appropriate page in my directory.